# Store value in a variable after using select statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

How to store the value of the `PolicyID` returned from database in an integer variable in `C#`?

I am using SQL server 2005.

```
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection();
        dataConnection.ConnectionString =
            @"Data Source=JAGMIT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SumooHAgentDB;Integrated Security=True";

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand();
        dataCommand.Connection = dataConnection;
        dataCommand.CommandText = ("select PolicyID from Policies where PolicyID=(select max(PolicyID) from Policies)");



        dataConnection.Open();
        dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dataConnection.Close();
```

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a `C#` variable or a `TSQL` variable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants a C# variable

Comment: I'm too, that's why I deleted my answer, but it's always best to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method, like this:

```
command.CommandText = @"select max(PolicyID) from Policies";
int maxPolicyId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Also, if you're doing this to insert a new Policy row with a unique ID, you must not do it like this, because it's entirely possible that a different Policies row will be inserted between the select and the insert.

Instead, use an `IDENTITY` column or a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` column.

**EDIT**: To use this in your code, do this:

```
int maxId;
using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=JAGMIT-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SumooHAgentDB;Integrated Security=True"))
using (SqlCommand dataCommand = 
        new SqlCommand("select max(PolicyID) from Policies", dataConnection)) {

    dataConnection.Open();
    maxId = Convert.ToInt32(dataCommand.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Comment: i get an error....
Specified cast is not valid..
in --maxId = (int)dataCommand.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: What type is PolicyID in the database?  Try replacing the cast with `Convert.ToInt32` or replacing `int` with `decimal`.

Comment: it is int in the database... i tried this---maxId =Convert.ToInt32((int)dataCommand.ExecuteScalar());.... still same error

Comment: actually it is smallint.. but will that make any difference??

Comment: Remove the `(int)` part and try again.  I've updated the answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @id INTEGER
SELECT @id=PolicyID FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you just insert a new record into that policy table and now you want the ID given?
Then instead of a max(), use

```
SELECT SCOPY_IDENTITY()
```

to get the value that was assigned to *your* record, not to a record that happened to be inserted moments later.

Comment: how do i put this in my above statement
and store it in a variable... which is my main question??/
thanks

Comment: You can put this or any other query in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Policies')` to get the value that was created for your record. To learn more about the differences between `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` AND `IDENT_CURRENT('tablename')`, check out this [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/).